# Switch off UTF escaping in JsonBuilder

Tags: json, servlets, groovy

I'm trying to use JsonBuilder in groovy servlet (extending HttpServlet)
Here is a snippet:

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     response.setContentType('text/plain')
     response.setCharacterEncoding('utf-8')

     def pw = response.getWriter()
     pw.println(new JsonBuilder(['city': 'Москва']))
     pw.println([сity: 'Москва'])
  }
```

The output is

```
{"city":"\u041C\u043E\u0441\u043A\u0432\u0430"}
{сity=Москва}
```

I just don't know nothing about UTF escaping in JsonBuilder, googling also did not give my anything valuable. So I guess I'm stuck.

Does anybody know how to get the output for json exactly in same form as we get the output for regular groovy object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as JavaScript and/or JSON goes, it *is* the exact same output.

You can easily [confirm this yourself](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0):

```
'Москва' == '\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430'; // true
```

What you're seeing are [Unicode string escape sequences](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode), which are defined by the ECMAScript specification (JavaScript) and are allowed in [JSON](http://json.org/) as well.

That said, I wouldn't worry about it too much, but if you insist on disabling the string escapes, you can use the `JsonOutput` object:

```
JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString());
```

Comment: Sharon, well, it is not exactly the same output in sense that first string is escaped while second is not, and that is exactly what this question about )))

Comment: @shabunc I know — I'm just pointing out that as far as JS/JSON are concerned, there is no difference at all; you shouldn’t worry too much about it.

Comment: got your point. though not sure it is always  harmless - json data can be used in plenty of non EcmaScript involved scenarios. For example, personally me need this not for front end.

Comment: @shabunc But if you do `new JsonSlurper().parseText( new JsonBuilder(['city': 'Москва']).toString() )` (convert to escaped JSON, then load this Json back into Groovy), you get `['city':'Москва']` as expected.  It *is* the same thing...

Comment: @tim_yates - well, in one sense it is same thing, in other - it isn't - is is different sequence of bytes in servlet response output, isn't it?

Comment: @shabunc shouldn't be...  You're arguing that `0x0A` is different to `10`.  It's the same exact thing, just with a different representation...

Comment: @tim_yates, I'm talkni about exactly the same http servlet response. How can it be not different sequence of bytes???

Comment: @shabunc `assert '\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430'.length() == 6` it's the same 6 chars.  Also: `assert '\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430'.getBytes( 'UTF-8' ) == 'Москва'.getBytes( 'UTF-8' )` passes.  You get the same 12 bytes for both representations `[-48, -100, -48, -66, -47, -127, -48, -70, -48, -78, -48, -80]`

Comment: @tim_yates-  but how? I'm not arguing I'm just trying to understand you. How browser distincts those two string and shows first string escaped while second - not?

Comment: JsonOutput is escaping the characters, nothing is disabled by the prettyPrint

Answer (score 25):

I have encountered the same issue, and the above methods didn't work.
However this did:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/StringEscapeUtils.html

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript(JsonOutput.toJson('Москва'))
```

Comment: It should me mentioned there that unescaping of json may lead to XSS vulnerability, e.g. when malefactor sends `{"foo":"</script><script>alert(\'XSS\')</script>"}`

Comment: This method can not be used when values contains double quotes: `println groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript(
                JsonOutput.toJson([key: """aaa<>"'&中文111"""])
)` output `{"key":"aaa<>"'&中文111"}` which is not a valid json because the middle double quote.

Comment: downvoted due to the issue @btpka3 already pointed out (it may be fine for some, but the restriction should be pointed out in the answer

Answer (score -1):

I've found it, I've found it.
So if you are as stubborn as me and don't want to recognize that (in a very wide range of applications) escaped sequence is exactly the same as non-escape, you can just use `JsonOuput` object, which is in the same standard  package, groovy.xml.*:

`JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString())`

If somebody's answer will be more detailed, I will delete my own answer and will mark the other answer as accepted. So I encourage you )))

Comment: I've incorporated this answer into mine. I think my answer summarizes this entire thread, now :)